# Show Firebase HTML-formatted text inside TextView

Tags: android, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, textview

I have a Text Editor inside my app, formatting watherver I want into HTML. But I've got a problem **when retrieving** this from the server (Firestore), because it's showing the whole text+codes, like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br><font color="green">Duis non arcu porttitor, laoreet arcu et, egestas justo.</font><br><b>Mauris non pharetra augue, id <i>maximus tellus</i>. Vivamus in sapien nisi.</b>
```

So this is what is loading inside the TextView, **instead of formatted** text like it should be. Does anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Html.fromHtml`. It will format your text (html) to display.

```
val message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br><font color="green">Duis non arcu porttitor, laoreet arcu et, egestas justo.</font><br><b>Mauris non pharetra augue, id <i>maximus tellus</i>. Vivamus in sapien nisi.</b>"

binding.tvMessage.text =
            Html.fromHtml(message, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
```

UPDATE:

You are doing it wrong way.

```
txtPostDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(postDescription, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Comment: Hi I tried it but it's not working...
`//SET POST DESCRIPTION
        txtPostDesc.setText(postDescription);
        HtmlCompat.fromHtml(String.valueOf(txtPostDesc), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);`

Comment: it's not showing the formatted text colors, but whatever. It's working!